# Having trouble publishing JointState msg from Arduino

Tags: ros, arduino, dynamixel, ros-melodic, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I am currently creating my own robotic arm actuated with Dynamixel motors.
The point of my code is to read the motor's position with an Arduino Mega and fulfill a sensor_msgs/JointState msg to be published over ROS on a /joint_state topic in order to get a feedback.
Rosserial is usually working quite well, but due to some mistakes, I supposed in my arduino's code, the /joint_state topic is empty when I do a `rostopic echo /joint_states` (nothing is being published).

---

Here's my arduino code:

```
#include <DynamixelSerial.h> //rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0 _baud:=115200
#include <ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/JointState.h>

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

sensor_msgs::JointState robot_state;
ros::Publisher pub("joint_states", &robot_state);

int posJoint;

char robot_id = "arm";
char *joint_name[6] = {"joint_01", "joint_02", "joint_03", "joint_04", "joint_05", "joint_06"};
float pos[6];
float vel[6];
float eff[6];

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  nh.getHardware()->setBaud(115200);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(pub);
  delay(1000);

  Dynamixel.setSerial(&Serial1); // &Serial - Arduino UNO/NANO/MICRO, &Serial1, &Serial2, &Serial3 - Arduino Mega
  Dynamixel.begin(1000000,2);  // Inicialize the servo at 1 Mbps and Pin Control 2
  delay(1000);
  Dynamixel.moveSpeed(1,512,512); //Home position
  Dynamixel.moveSpeed(2,512,512);
  Dynamixel.moveSpeed(3,512,512);
  Dynamixel.moveSpeed(4,512,512);
  Dynamixel.moveSpeed(5,512,512);
  Dynamixel.moveSpeed(6,512,512);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  for(int id = 1; id <= 6; id++){ // Fulfill the arrays whith motor readings
    posJoint = posToRadians(Dynamixel.readPosition(id));
    pos[id] = posJoint;
    vel[id] = 0.5; // Value only for testing
    eff[id] = 0.1; // Value only for testing
  }

  // Fulfill the sensor_msg/JointState msg
  robot_state.name_length = 6;
  robot_state.velocity_length = 6;
  robot_state.position_length = 6;
  robot_state.effort_length = 6;

  robot_state.header.stamp = nh.now();
  robot_state.header.frame_id = robot_id;
  robot_state.name = joint_name;
  robot_state.position = pos;
  robot_state.velocity = vel;
  robot_state.effort = eff;

  pub.publish( &robot_state);
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(10);
  
}

double posToRadians(int posInt) // Dynamixel position into radians
{
  float position_degrees = map(posInt, 0, 1023, -150, 150);
  float position_radians = (position_degrees * 3.14)/180;

  return position_radians;
}
```

---

Specs:

- ROS melodic (up to date)
- Ubuntu mate 18.04
- Arduino IDE 1.8.8

Feel free to ask me for more informations

Have a nice day

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345823/having-trouble-publishing-jointstate-msg-from-arduino/) by [Benjamin C](https://answers.ros.org/users/52231/benjamin-c/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2020-03-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-04**:
`rosserial` on Arduinos requires some more bookkeeping when dealing with arrays.

Have you see [wiki/rosserial/Overview/Limitations - Arrays](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Overview/Limitations#Arrays) and made sure to do everything it mentions?

**Comment by [Benjamin C](https://answers.ros.org/users/52231/benjamin-c/) on 2020-03-04**:
No, I hadn't seen it. I might have to add `Header header;` and replace `sensor_msgs::JointState robot_state;` by `sensor_msgs::JointState[] robot_state;` I'll check if it works later.
Thank you !

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-04**:
No, that's not what that page tells you. The message shown there is just an example.

Arrays in messages have an extra field when used with `rosserial`: `<array_field_name>_length`, as lengths of arrays / lists cannot be determined from a pointer alone.

You don't appear to be setting that field, so most likely `rosserial` assumes the message it receives contains zero-length arrays.

**Comment by [Benjamin C](https://answers.ros.org/users/52231/benjamin-c/) on 2020-03-04**:
Isn't it what I have already done there ?

```
robot_state.name_length = 6;
  robot_state.velocity_length = 6;
  robot_state.position_length = 6;
  robot_state.effort_length = 6
```

Thank you for your help

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-04**:
You're correct. That would be those fields. I'd missed them when reading your question.

I'd also assumed that with "empty", you mean there are messages on `/joint_states`, but they don't contain any information. In fact, re-reading, I now assume you mean there no messages published at all. Correct?

**Comment by [Benjamin C](https://answers.ros.org/users/52231/benjamin-c/) on 2020-03-04**:
Yes, there is nothing at all published on /`joint_states`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-05**:
Then I would suggest to take a step back: can you publish *any* message from your Arduino code to the ROS side?

Start with a simple `std_msgs/Int32` or something similar.

**Comment by [Benjamin C](https://answers.ros.org/users/52231/benjamin-c/) on 2020-03-05**:
Ufortunately yes, simple messages work fine and also all the Arduino exemple codes working as well.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-05**:
How is that unfortunate? It tells us that at least the infrastructure is working.

Could you try with a single joint (ie: single name, single position, velocity and acceleration)? I have a suspicion the full `JointState` message is too big for the configured serial buffer size.

**Comment by [Benjamin C](https://answers.ros.org/users/52231/benjamin-c/) on 2020-03-05**:
I tried and it still doesn't work. Plus I forget to mention that when I do a `rostopic list` and a `rosotpic echo` it makes the communication restart:

```
[INFO] [1583446774.076031]: Requesting topics...
[INFO] [1583446774.226598]: Setup publisher on joint_states [sensor_msgs/JointState]
[ERROR] [1583446789.223287]: Lost sync with device, restarting...
```

Thank you for your patience.

PS: I tried a fix by increasing arduino's buffer size to 256 but nothing changes.

**Comment by [Benjamin C](https://answers.ros.org/users/52231/benjamin-c/) on 2020-03-11**:
I've got an idea, could it be due to `name()` and `position()` available on Arduino in conflict with `robot_state.name` and `robot_state.position` ?

I'm stuck and I can't find another solution to give moveit some feedback..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-11**:
Unfortunately I don't know, and I'm not in a position to help you (as I can't reproduce your issue).

There is probably something really "stupid" you/we are not seeing here, which prevents this from working.

The fact that an (almost) empty message also doesn't work is strange.

**Comment by [Benjamin C](https://answers.ros.org/users/52231/benjamin-c/) on 2020-03-11**:
I figured out, check the answer and again thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've solved my problem, that was the `nh.spinOnce();` that wasn't called quickly enough.
The fullfilement of my array `pos` was slow because of the `Dynamixel.readPosition(id))` statement.
This leads to a bad sync between the Arduino and ROS.
So if you have the same error as me:

```
[INFO] [1583446774.076031]: Requesting topics...
[INFO] [1583446774.226598]: Setup publisher on joint_states [sensor_msgs/JointState]
[ERROR] [1583446789.223287]: Lost sync with device, restarting...
```

Just make sure that `spinOnce();` is called at a sufficiently high frequency.

---

Originally posted by [Benjamin C](https://answers.ros.org/users/52231/benjamin-c/) with karma: 40 on 2020-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0